# chid processes of a given process by PID

Tags: shell, unix, process, csh, tcsh

Can anyone tell me how to get the child processes of a given process by PID using shell commands bash or tcsh?

i' ve tried many options of 'ps' command

ps --pid $pid, but i don't know if it's correct.

thanks

Comment: please be more specific about what you want to do with these PIDs, just look at them, or put them in an array, or iterate thru them a kill them or ??? AND as stackOverflow is about helping people fix their broken code, please indicate what you have tried, the best results your getting and what you think is the problem. Good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of all child process spawned by a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663196/how-to-get-list-of-all-child-process-spawned-by-a-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use:

```
pgrep -P $your_process1_pid
```