# wait command not working on parent process

Tags: bash, shell

I'm executing a set of customised in-house commands and using the `wait` command to see whether the set of commands finishes before moving on to the rest of the script.

```
function wait_f() {
 local command; command="$@"
 exec ${command} &
 pid=$!
 echo "PID: ${pid}"
 wait ${pid}
 #timeout 300 tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null
 echo "Exit status: $?"
}


wait_f <customised command1>
wait_f <customised command2 (multi worded separated by space)>
```

Problem being, the function completes with exit status *0* but the process is still ongoing, like this:

```
PROGRESS: ====>      [ 55%]
```

I need the function to wait until the `PROGRESS` is 100% and then move on.

I tried `wait` and other commands as well, like `timeout 300 tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null` , but with no luck.. What am I missing ?

Comment: There's no need for `exec`.

Comment: I tried `wait_f sleep 5`. The function waited for 5 seconds between printing the PID and the exit status.

Comment: It sounds like your customized command is forking a child and then exiting. The shell can only wait for its child process, not grandchildren.

Comment: @Barmar : Thanks firstly.. Yes I tried without exec as well.. Same result. ah interesting.. How can wait for the grandchildren process in case, thats the case.

Comment: You can't wait for grandchildren. If this is an in-house program, can you change it so it waits for its own children before exiting?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that exec has anything to do with the problem. It's just unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry dont have much of an idea, on changing the inhouse command to wait

Comment: Why does it fork in the first place? Maybe it already has an option to not do that.

Comment: I don't think related to your main issue, but `exec $command` without quotes is not what you want.  You almost certainly want `exec "$@"`.  Attempting to emulate that with `local command="$@"; exec "$command"` is a mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure about that bbehaviour to be honest.. Thanks for exec "$@".. Customised commands exits with return value 0 but the deployment goes on in the background.

Comment: If you _did_ want to store `$@` and use it later, doing that correctly (in a way that didn't corrupt the contents) would be `local -a command; command=( "$@" )`, and then `exec "${command[@]}"` (or, in this case, just `"${command[@]}"`, because Barmar is right that the `exec` is pointless when combined with `&` -- and if you _didn't_ have the `&`, `exec`'s side effect of terminating execution of the shell interpreter by replacing it with the newly-executed command would be unwanted).

Comment: The variable assignment `local command; command="$@"` should use another name [since `command` is already the name of a shell builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_(Unix)).

Comment: @agc, ...but variables and commands are in two different namespaces, so I hardly see how it matters. `ls="whatever"` doesn't change how `ls` works -- unless you're worried about throwing off syntax highlighting engines?

Comment: @voltas, ...btw, if you _do_ need to wait for all grandchild processes to exit, that _is_ a doable thing -- one way to do it I frequently follow is using advisory locking; if the child process holds a lock and its children inherit it, waiting for that file to become available for a new exclusive lock will block until those children exit. If we don't already have an answer teaching the technique elsewhere on the site I'd be happy to add one here, though I'd be surprised if it wasn't covered.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, It's a kind of code obfuscation.  And when there's a typo, (say the programmer forgets to type a `$`, so `$command` comes out as `command`), any results are more likely to be confusing.

Comment: ...indeed, the technique is already taught elsewhere on the site, on one of the answers to [How to wait on all child (and grandchild etc) process spawned by a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18663541/14122) (the link is to the _specific_ answer I recommend, not the accepted one).

Comment: @voltas, ...btw, `function something() {` merges two syntax variants (legacy ksh and POSIX sh) in such a way as to not be compatible with _either_ ksh or POSIX sh. I strongly recommend using the POSIX form, `something() {` with no `function` keyword. See both entries in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete -- it's discussed in both the first and 3rd tables.

Comment: @agc, `$command` isn't acceptable code in any circumstances. You'd need it to be an array, thus `"${command[@]}"`, to avoid the bugs described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), so we're getting pretty far away from trivial-typo territory.

Comment: Thanks a lot Charles.. I'll try your suggestions.